# Git - How to handle changes in locally renamed files when pulling from a parent repo

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, git-merge-conflict

## Question

I'm having issues pulling a parent repository into a fork and properly resolving conflicts.
It appears that if a file is renamed in the fork and is modified by both the parent and the fork, git only treats it as being `deleted by us`.

This happens when I use `git pull /path/to/parent master` and `git merge upstream/master` [(with upstream configured)](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork).

How can I use git such that I am prompted to resolve the conflict on the renamed file instead of having git assume the file was `deleted by us`?

## Setup

Here is a setup to demonstrate the issue I'm having. This can be done locally or in an online managed system (I'm experiencing this in Azure DevOps / VSTS).

I've duplicated most of the steps below in GitHub with these two repos:

- parent - https://github.com/Daniel-Khodabakhsh/TestForkPull
- fork - https://github.com/Daniel-H-K/TestForkPull

You can clone the fork and do a `git pull https://github.com/Daniel-Khodabakhsh/TestForkPull.git master` to see the issue.

#### Manual steps:

1. Create a small project with files with arbitrary text named `A.txt`, `B.txt`, and `C.txt` in a repo path `/path/to/parent`.
2. Create a fork of this repo by copying it to `/path/to/fork` and switch to this path.
3. In this new fork repo, rename the files in the following way and commit. I did it with the OS instead of using `git mv` but this shouldn't matter because of how git works.

```
A.txt → X.txt
B.txt → Y.txt
C.txt → Z.txt
```

4. Verify git recognises the rename by running `git diff --name-status HEAD~1` and noticing the `'R'` indicating a detected rename.

```
$ git diff --name-status HEAD~1
R100    A.txt   X.txt
R100    B.txt   Y.txt
R100    C.txt   Z.txt
```

5. In the parent repo, make modifications to the contents of files `A.txt` and `B.txt`.
6. In the fork repo, make modifications to the contents of files `Y.txt` and `Z.txt`.

Up to here, you'd have the following files in both repos:

```
A.txt → X.txt - Modified in parent
B.txt → Y.txt - Modified in both
C.txt → Z.txt - Modified in fork
```

7. "pull" the parent repo into the fork by running `git pull /path/to/parent master` from the fork path. You will get the following output:

```
$ git pull /path/to/parent/ master
remote: Enumerating objects: 7, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
From D:/path/to/parent
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
CONFLICT (modify/delete): B.txt deleted in HEAD and modified in ba146eba53bd7d51c9977238d9d62b56f7a984f7. Version ba146eba53bd7d51c9977238d9d62b56f7a984f7 of B.txt left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

```
$ git status
On branch master
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)

Changes to be committed:

        modified:   X.txt

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)

        deleted by us:   B.txt
```

Here `X.txt` correctly only shows the modification from the parent repo, `Z.txt` is correctly untouched with changes from the fork repo, but `Y.txt` (`B.txt`) is not properly shown as in conflict, but rather, shown as only being `deleted by us`.

Answer (score 1):

> It appears that if a file is renamed in the fork and is modified by both the parent and the fork, git only treats it as being deleted by us.

Note that git doesn't track file renames or moves. This means that when a file is moved on on branch and modified on another branch, you will get merge conflicts as you have seen.

> How can I use git such that I am prompted to resolve the conflict on the renamed file instead of having git assume the file was deleted by us?

You have to manually make the modifications in the moved version of the file.

Answer (score 0):

note : github shows some extra chars (a `crlf`maybe ?) at the end of B.txt, which disappear both in "modified B.txt" and "renamed Y.txt". This may add to the confusion in detecting renames for git.

---